# String is not a subtype of int

Tags: flutter, search

[image]

I want to show suggestions in the search bar. But the highlighted portion of the image is not working i.e when the user inputs some query, it throws an error.

> type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your `snapshot.data` actually is, you are not handling it correctly.

I suggest you don't operate on raw maps (I guess you got them from a json webservice response?) but instead use model classes in your application, so that you have type safety and don't have to guess and get runtime errors when your guesses turned out to be wrong.

I don't know your models or your backend, so I can only link you this general guideline:
[Flutter: Data and Backend - Serializing JSON inside model classes](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-inside-model-classes)

Answer (score 0):

> String is not a subtype of int

This clearly states that, somewhere in your code, you had to pass an int but instead you are passing a String.

If my guess is right, one among this snapshot.data['shop_items']['productTitle'], is supposed to be an int, instead of a String.